# html5 img and other void elements syntax - invalid syntax on Netbeans 7.0.1?

Tags: html, image

I've read that `<img></img>` (is illegal);
I've read that `/>` is optional and it's only there for "transitional policies".

Can this be a correct syntax for img element?

```
<img src="/somepath" alt="required foo">
```

I'm asking this because Netbeans 7.0.1 detects that has an error and made me wondering.
It does the same for other void elements like: `<br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a correct syntax if `src` wasn't empty!

As the question has been edited, yes, it's a correct syntax for HTML5.

EDIT: but you can explicitly close your element too

http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#elements

> In XHTML, the XML syntactic requirements dictate that this must be made explicit using either an explicit end tag, as above, or the empty element syntax. This is achieved by inserting a slash at the end of the start tag immediately before the right angle bracket.
>   [...]
>   Authors may optionally choose to use this same syntax for void elements in the HTML syntax as well.

Comment: :p question changed. So, the last / is not required. (my IDE netbeans gives an error if I don't put it, perhaps it's a bug);

Comment: I don't use netbeans. Is your doctype `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm on .php file but that should represent a problem since the editor recognizes things like "article" and "section"; <img /> works. The same goes for <br> (it also throws an error);

Comment: So netbeans is wrong. I don't know anything about its configuration but you can close your tags staying valid HTML5 (answer edited).

Comment: I know but that's mainly on two scenarios: "hard time one may have for doing the transition" so, as a "transition policy" - or, as a specific request for XML document validation as well.

Comment: Lol indeed. ;) +1 to that. :)

Comment: After some consideration, I must still advice AGAINST this for the moment since this not just a question for USERS but also a question for BROWSERS if we don't self close this, older browsers may read it as start tags, and screw the all html rendering on the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your syntax is correct according to HTML5. It does not allow self closing for void elements (like img).

**Addendum:**

As for your NetBeans issue - try right clicking yellow attention mark on your 1st line of code if you have it - it should allow you to change HTML version for a syntax checker.

Comment: don't have any attention mark there. I will report a bug on netbeans website.